# Ubuntu 16.04 LTS freezes during installation

Tags: boot, 16.04, dual-boot, system-installation, live-usb

I was trying to install Ubuntu 16.04 LTS on my friends brand new computer.

We've prepared live usb with ubuntu tool. After choosing option in grub some grey and white stripes appear on black screen. Then installation freezes after loading screen disappears. Loading mouse doesn't spin and installation window doesn't appear. We are able to open console by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>, but nothing other happens.

We've follow askubuntu and tried to change `nouveau.modeset` in grub, but it didn't help.

There is already Windows 7 installed. During installation there were problem with USB 3.0 driver and it had to be added to live usb manualy before installation.

Computer specifications are as follows:

- MSI B350 Tomahawk motherboard
- AMD A8-9600 CPU
- integrated GPU
- SSD drive.

Where I can look for solution?
Thanks for every tip in advance.

Comment: Have you tried nomodeset?

Comment: No, I've read about it, but I don't exactly know how to do it with live usb. I tried setting nouveau.modeset to zero as I mentioned. Could you help me finding some good tutorial?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/38780/how-do-i-set-nomodeset-after-ive-already-installed-ubuntu

Comment: Thanks a lot, that has helped. Now we have problem with GPU drivers. There are for situations: when drivers are installed and there is no nomodeset we have black screen, with nomodeset there is loop on log in. Then we have uninstalled drivers: with no nomodeset everything work veeery slowly and we can't log in, with nomodeset it's working but  not smoothly - windows are stuttering.

Comment: This is often difficult. What I did was boot with nomodeset and then install the video drivers.  But getting the correct drivers and installing them correctly is challenging and varies from system to system.  If you edit your question, explain the current situation, and give information about your video card, someone may be able to help.